# Excel function that works out the average by first excluding all zeros and then excluding the minimum and maximum value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have around 300 values on an excel spreadsheet (many of which are zero) and I want to work out the average by excluding the zeros, the highest value and the lowest value after zero. What would be an appropriate formula?

Thanks in advance.

**edit: What I tried so far**

Assuming my values are in A1:A300 I did the following:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A100, A1:A100, "<>0", A1:A100, "<>SMALL(A1:A100, COUNTIF(A1: A100,0)+1)", A1:A100, "<>LARGE(A1: A100, COUNTIF(A1: A100))")
```

It successfully discards the zeros, but not the max or minimum.

Comment: What did you already try. At which point did you get stuck?

Comment: Assuming my values are in A1:A300 I did the following: =AVERAGEIFS(A1:A100, A1:A100, "<>0", A1:A100, "<>SMALL(A1:A100, COUNTIF(A1: A100,0)+1)", A1:A100, "<>LARGE(A1: A100, COUNTIF(A1: A100))"). It successfully discards the zeros, but not the max or minimum.

Comment: If your table contains the following values, 1, 5, 9, 12, 3, 0, 0, 0, 30, then you want the average of 5, 9, 12 and 3 which would be 7.25. I excluded the 0's, 1 as it was the lowest value and 30 as it was the highest. 
Also, what happens if you have multiple equal values at either the highest or lowest numbers? So, if I had the same numbers above but with two additional 30's (1, 5, 9, 12, 3, 0, 0, 0, 30, 30, 30) would I ignore all 30's or just the one?

Comment: @user3396592. Feel free to use the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1098348/edit) link to add that to the post rather than in a comment. Also, what  if 0 is the lowest value ?

Comment: In ` "<>SMALL(A1:A100, COUNTIF(A1: A100,0)+1)"` the  `SMALL(A1:A100, COUNTIF(A1: A100,0)+1)` is not evaluated but considered as a string. Using `&` solves at least one problem: ` "<>"&SMALL(A1:A100, COUNTIF(A1: A100,0)+1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the result should be print into one cell without using any other cells for printing interim results. This probably only works with array formulas, VBA code or database queries (answer of [vembutech](https://superuser.com/a/1098352/504096)).

### Array Formulas

See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-3be0c791-3f89-4644-a062-8e6e9ecee523) and [Create an array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) for details.

### One solution

In my example, the values to average are in the grid cells A1 to A11.

This formula solves the problem:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((A1:A11=MAX(A1:A11))+(A1:A11=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$11=0,"",$A$1:$A$11)))+(A1:A11=0),"",A1:A11))
```

after inserting it, you need to type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (not just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, see [Create an array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)).

### Idea behind this solution

The `AVERAGE` function (other then `AVERAGEA`) calculates the average value of all cells that contain a number. Cells containing a string or a boolean/logical are ignored. What we will do is: set those cells to "" (an empty string), which equal 0, equal the minimum cell value (0 excluded) or equal the maximum cell value. Basically, we use this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(_TODO_,"",A1:A11))
```

Now we need to replace the *TODO* by some content (the three described situation). These three situations are tested by:

```
A1:A11=MAX(A1:A11)
A1:A11=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$11=0,"",$A$1:$A$11))
A1:A11=0
```

The second test is a bit tricky: We want to exclude the '0' (zero) from calculating the min value. The `MIN` function ignores all non-number values (e.g. an empty string ""). The `IF($A$1:$A$11=0,"",$A$1:$A$11)` sets all cells to "" which are equal zero. All remaining cells keep their original values.

Now we combine the three test. This is done by putting brackets around the three tests and combining them by an `+`, which represents a logical `OR`.

```
(A1:A11=MAX(A1:A11))+(A1:A11=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$11=0,"",$A$1:$A$11)))+(A1:A11=0)
```

This combined test is now filled into our formula at the top, replacing `_TODO_`:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((A1:A11=MAX(A1:A11))+(A1:A11=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$11=0,"",$A$1:$A$11)))+(A1:A11=0),"",A1:A11))
```

### Another solution

Based on [user3396592](https://superuser.com/q/1098348/504096)'s approach one can also write:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A11,A1:A11,"<>0",A1:A11,"<>"&MAX(A1:A11), A1:A11,"<>"&MIN(IF($A$1:$A$11=0,"",$A$1:$A$11)))
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope, the below formulla will meet your requirement,

> =QUERY(A:A,"select avg(A) where A > 0")

Say for example, if you are having 100 numbers of zero rows out of 300, this will skip the 100 rows and calculate average for the remaing 200 rows.

Comment: Thanks, but then how would you exclude the minimum and maximum values?

Comment: I'm not aware of a `QUERY` function in Excel 2010, could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: @user3396592 I could not get this function work either. But if it was working: It uses SQL syntax. The correct select statement might be something like `SELECT AVG(A) WHERE (A > 0)  AND (A <> (SELECT MAX(A)))  AND (A <> (SELECT MIN(A) WHERE A <> 0));`.